# How to make Matlab to wait until the PDE toolbox computes the solution?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, pde

I want to extract mesh and solution data using script from the PDE toolbox however, when i run the following script the code does provide the pde solution but it doesn't seem to get the data which might be because it doesn't wait for GUI to complete. However when I run the commands to get the data separately, after i get the PDE solution, it does work but that would mean running the getdata commands separately in another script or in the workspace. Therefore, I want to incorporate everything in one script and it should provide PDE solution and data in single run. Any help would be greatly appreciated. The script is as follows.

```
function pdemodel
[pde_fig,ax]=pdeinit;
pdetool('appl_cb',9);
set(ax,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1.5 1]);
set(ax,'PlotBoxAspectRatio',[1 0.66666666666666663 1]);
set(ax,'XLim',[0 2]);
set(ax,'YLim',[0 2]);
set(ax,'XTickMode','auto');
set(ax,'YTickMode','auto');

% Geometry description:
pderect([0 1 1 0],'R1');
set(findobj(get(pde_fig,'Children'),'Tag','PDEEval'),'String','R1')

% Boundary conditions:
pdetool('changemode',0)
pdesetbd(4,...
'neu',...
1,...
'0',...
'sin(2*t)')
pdesetbd(3,...
'neu',...
1,...
'0',...
'0')
pdesetbd(2,...
'neu',...
1,...
'0',...
'0')
pdesetbd(1,...
'neu',...
1,...
'0',...
'0')

% Mesh generation:
setappdata(pde_fig,'Hgrad',1.3);
setappdata(pde_fig,'refinemethod','regular');
setappdata(pde_fig,'jiggle',char('on','mean',''));
pdetool('initmesh')
pdetool('refine')

% PDE coefficients:
pdeseteq(2,...
'1.0',...
'0',...
'(0)+(0).*(0.0)',...
'(1.0).*(1.0)',...
'0:0.1:10',...
'0.0',...
'0.0',...
'[0 100]')
setappdata(pde_fig,'currparam',...
['1.0';...
'1.0';...
'1.0';...
'0  ';...
'0  ';...
'0.0'])

% Solve parameters:
setappdata(pde_fig,'solveparam',...
str2mat('0','1872','10','pdeadworst',...
'0.5','longest','0','1E-4','','fixed','Inf'))

% Plotflags and user data strings:
setappdata(pde_fig,'plotflags',[1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 101 1 0 0 0 0 1]);
setappdata(pde_fig,'colstring','');
setappdata(pde_fig,'arrowstring','');
setappdata(pde_fig,'deformstring','');
setappdata(pde_fig,'heightstring','');

% Solve PDE:
pdetool('solve')

%Get mesh data p,e,t and solution u from the PDE toolbox:
pde_fig=findobj(allchild(0),'flat','Tag','PDETool');
if isempty(pde_fig)
    error('PDE Toolbox GUI not active.')
end
u = get(findobj(pde_fig,'Tag','PDEPlotMenu'),'UserData');
h=findobj(get(pde_fig,'Children'),'flat','Tag','PDEMeshMenu');
hp=findobj(get(h,'Children'),'flat','Tag','PDEInitMesh');
he=findobj(get(h,'Children'),'flat','Tag','PDERefine');
ht=findobj(get(h,'Children'),'flat','Tag','PDEMeshParam');
p=get(hp,'UserData'); 
e=get(he,'UserData');
t=get(ht,'UserData');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems due to the way you've defined your function.

```
function pdemodel
```

This definition implies that it does not receive any input and does not return any output.

In the body of the function you actually get the matrices `u`, `p`, `e` and `t` (you can set a breakpoint at, for example,

```
u = get(findobj(pde_fig,'Tag','PDEPlotMenu'),'UserData');
```

execute the code step by step and check the values).

The problem is that the [scope of the variables of a function](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/base-and-function-workspaces.html) is limited to the function itself (unless you define them as [global](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html) - which is not the best), so at the end of the execution of your function, the values of `u`, `p`, `e` and `t` (and of any other variable in the function) are not available in the MatLab `base workspace`.

A simple solution solution could be to modify the definition of the function by specifying some output, as follows:

```
function [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel
```

where `[u,p,e,t]` is the list of the varaibles (computed in the function) you want to be returned.

Then you can call the function as follow:

```
[u,p,e,t]=pdemodel
```

this will allows you to have the output matrices `u`, `p`, `e` and `t` available in the workspace.

In the same way, you can define some *input* varaible in the definition of your function, so you will not have to hardcode their values in the function body.

In this case, the definition of the function could, for example, something like this:

```
function [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel(var_1, var_2, var_3)
```

where `var_1`, `var_2` and `var_3` are three values you can use in the function.

For example, you can specify, as input the values for the `dataaspectratio`:

```
function [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel(var_1, var_2, var_3)
% some code
% set(ax,'DataAspectRatio',[1 1.5 1]);
set(ax,'DataAspectRatio',[var_1 var_2 var_3]);
```

You can call your function:

```
[u,p,e,t]=pdemodel(1, 1.5, 1)
```

You can make the definition of your function more "flexible" by using:

- [varargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html) to be allowed providing a variable number of input parameters to your function
- [nargin](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) to get the number of input provided
- [varargout](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargout.html) to be allowed providing a variable number of outputparameters to your function
- [nargout](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) to get the  number of output arguments specified in the call

Hope this helps,

Qapla'

Comment: hello Raffa. I have tried calling the function just as you described [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel. It did work however the output is only one variable which is written first in this case variable 'u'. So basically which ever variable is written first when defining function only that variable is the output and not the following variables in this case p,e,t. Secondly the output matrix for variable 'u' is being named as 'ans' in the workspace but not 'u'?

Comment: I could answer to your question only late this evening, sorry.

Comment: Here I'm. If you have modified the definition of the function as follows: `function [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel` in order to get the output values `u`, `p`, `e` and `t` in the workspace, you have to call the function as follows: `[u,p,e,t]=pdemodel`, otherwise, even if you have modified the deinition of the function, if you call it as follows: `pdemodel` (that is without specifying any output) you will get in the workspace only the first of the output specified in the function definition - in that case `u`, stored in the automatically created variable `ans`.

Comment: I modified the function as [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel and then called it as [u,p,e, t]=pdemodel but I get the error "undefined function or variable'pdemodel'

Comment: If you have defined the functiion as `function [u,p,e,t]=pdemodel` and you call it as `[u,p,e,t]=pdemodel` it should work. Is the folder in which you saved the `.m` in the MatLab `path`? Is the name of the `.m` file the same  as the name of the function (i. e. _pdemodel.m_)?

Comment: I tried removing the function from the main file (exported from PDE toolbox) and without using the functions when i run the main script only it works! I managed to get all the outputs without defining any function after the PDE toolbox computes the solution. Could you explain why this worked?